# Run a function inside a tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have created a function that reads certain strings from a list.

The function should be displayed (or rather called) inside a frame created with tkinter.

My idea was to create the function as a method of the frame class (or maybe as a method of a label) and to call the method with a new instance. The result was, that the content is displayed in the console.

my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

a = 1
b = -6
c = -5

def calc_x(y):
    x = 0
    if y == c:
        for i in range(1,len(data)):
            x = x + int(data[i][y])
            t = x/(len(data)-1)
        print str(t)+"%"
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(data)):
            x = x + int(data[i][y])
        print x 

class Fram(Frame):

    def __init__(self,tk,width,height):
        Frame.__init__(self,tk)
        self.config(width=width)
        self.config(height=height)
        self.config(bd=1)
        self.config(relief="solid")

square_frame = Fram(root,500,40).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=3,pady=3)

mainloop()
```

EDIT:

ok, thank you very much so far.
I added the "data" list as well as the souce URL.

How can I call the function with either of the variables (self.a/b/c) ?
When I create a instance of "Fram" it doesn't display the string.

```
from Tkinter import *
from urllib2 import *
import csv

root = Tk()

class Fram(Frame):

def __init__(self,tk,width,height):
    Frame.__init__(self,tk)
    self.config(width=width)
    self.config(height=height)
    self.config(bd=1)
    self.config(relief="solid")
    self.url = "http://data.nottinghamtravelwise.org.uk/parking.csv?noLocation=true?t=635509084580321642"
    self.webpage = urlopen(self.url)
    self.datareader = csv.reader(self.webpage.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
    self.data = list(self.datareader)
    self.a = 1
    self.b = -6
    self.c = -5
    self.value = self.calc_x(self.a)
    self.label = Label(self, text=self.value)
    self.label.pack()

def calc_x(self, y):
    x = 0
    if y == self.c:
        for i in range(1,len(data)):
            x = x + int(data[i][y])
            t = x/(len(data)-1)
        return str(t)+'%'
    else:
        for i in range(1,len(data)):
            x = x + int(data[i][y])
        return str(x)
```

Comment: What is actually wrong with the code so far? any error messages?

Comment: It is running smoothly. But I want to display the strings when calling the function inside the frame, instead of the console.

Comment: I have changed it so instantiating Fram will now show the string. What sort of condition do you want to occur so that it chooses between a, b or c? If you want all three to happen you could repeatedly call the function and pack a new label in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options, you can either use the Label widget or the Text Widget. The Label Widget is more useful for short strings and you would call like this:

```
self.label = Label(self, text="TEXT TO BE INSERTED")
self.label.pack()
```

The text widget can be accessed like this:

```
self.text = Text(self, height=30, width=30)
self.text.pack()
self.text.insert(END, "TEXT TO BE INSERTED")
```

Also by the sounds of it you should think about moving the function inside of the class and calling it from `__init__` with `self.calcx(y)`. That way your class will have access to all the information you need.

EDIT (try this out):

```
from Tkinter import *
from urllib2 import *
import csv

root = Tk()

class Fram(Frame):

    def __init__(self,tk,width,height):
        Frame.__init__(self,tk)
        self.config(width=width)
        self.config(height=height)
        self.config(bd=1)
        self.config(relief="solid")
        self.url = "http://data.nottinghamtravelwise.org.uk/parking.csv?noLocation=true?t=635509084580321642"
        self.webpage = urlopen(self.url)
        self.datareader = csv.reader(self.webpage.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
        self.data = list(self.datareader)
        self.a = 1
        self.b = -6
        self.c = -5
        self.value = self.calc_x(self.a, self.data)
        self.label = Label(self, text=self.value)
        self.label.pack()

    def calc_x(self, y, data):
        x = 0
        if y == self.c:
            for i in range(1,len(data)):
                x = x + int(data[i][y])
                t = x/(len(data)-1)
            return str(t)+'%'
        else:
            for i in range(1,len(data)):
                x = x + int(data[i][y])
            return str(x)

square_frame = Fram(root,500,40).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=3,pady=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You mean moving it inside the class as a method of the class?
Or just the function as it is, moving inside the class?

Comment: Move it in as a method. Define your variables in the `__init__` method and then call your method after. By the way shouldn't you be passing `c` and `data` to your function? otherwise they won't be visible inside.

Comment: Ok so I changed up the code a bit so it now runs without a hitch and displays the number 15007 in the window. Try it now!

Comment: ok thats amazing, thank you a lot. I want all three to be called, but I want to display them in a certain format:
"some text: " self.a        "some more text: " self.b ...

Could I call each of the the conditions in seperate methods?

Comment: In that case I would look at the different layout options that Tkinter has to offer because some are better suited to your needs. This contains a nice intro to them and there is more detail to be found elsewhere http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/. The nice thing about functions/methods is that they can be called multiple times. so you could do `self.value1 = self.calc_x(self.a, self.data)` and then `self.value2 = self.calcx(self.b, self.data`)`. So call the function for every new value and assign it to a new variable name.

Comment: I figured out a solution that suits my needs. Thank you very much for helping. With your hints I understood how the object oriented approach with tkinter works! :)

Comment: Cool no problem :) If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more attempts I figured out a very convenient solution.

Instead of using frames, the canvas item offers far more flexibility to place objects/strings.

```
from Tkinter import *
from urllib2 import *
import csv

url = "http://data.nottinghamtravelwise.org.uk/parking.csv?noLocation=true?t=635509084580321642"
webpage = urlopen(url)
datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
data = list(datareader)

class elements(Canvas):

    def __init__(self,tk,shape):
        Canvas.__init__(self,tk)
        self.config(width=600)
        self.method_a()

    def method_a(self):
        self.config(height=20)
        self.config(bd=1)
        self.config(relief="solid")
        self.create_text(300,10,text="Sample Text")

root = Tk()

first_element = elements(root,"method_a")
first_element.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=2)

mainloop()
```